# kasher a nonkosher Le Creuset pot?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

I have several Le Creuset pieces - Dutch ovens and casseroles - that I inherited.  They have not been used for 15 years, but definitely were used for non-kosher cooking; it's safe to assume they might have had pork cooked in them.  My daughter keeps kosher, and I would like to pass them on to her.  Is there a way for them to be made kosher?  She's been able to find out the answer for pots made of other materials, but not for the enamelled cast iron of Le Creuset.

Comment: Hi LEM. Welcome to Mi Yodeya. We don't offer practical advice to _halacha_ questions here. Your daughter should ask her rabbi if there is any way to make the pots kosher. I hope you'll stick around and participate in the site!